# vba sumifs multiple criteria in single column

Tags: arrays, vba, sumifs

lets say I have in columns A and B this:

```
A    5
A_1  3
A_2  2
A_3  3
A_4  4
```

and i want to do:

```
Application.SumIfs(range("b:b"), range("b:b"), {"A", "A_2"})
```

however this doesnt work, the array values.

I wish not to go through EVALUATION() (or [] equivalent) or not even do the loop through range.
So Im looking for a way to use multiple options on criteria values.

PS: SumIfs is just an example, because I have more conditions than just one, so If someone would suggest SumIf, then no, i have reasons not to use SumIf

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. the SUMIFS must be Late Bound: `Application.SumIfs` vs. `Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs`
2. Wrap in `Application.SumProduct`
3. Use `Array()`

---

```
Application.SumProduct(Application.SumIfs(range("b:b"), range("a:a"), Array("A", "A_2")))
```

Comment: can you explain Application.SumIfs vs Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs ?

Comment: `Application.SumIfs` is Late Bound, and the other is Early Bound.  If you use the Early Bound version it will not parse and you will get a parse error.  By removing the `WorksheetFunction` it allows it to work.

Comment: Nice! But, wouldn't it be `Application.SumIfs(range("b:b"), range("A:A"), Array("A", "A_2"))`?

Comment: @FaneDuru, yes, I just copied the OP's formula.

Comment: @Scott Craner: I was sure about that! It happened to me a lot of times. Just wanted to have there, on the answer code, the correct solution, for people not understanding too well how it works... :)

Comment: @ScottCraner, what is the purpose of nesting SUMIFS inside SUMPRODUCT? Seems SUMIFS function multiplies out the Boolean arrays and sums them? Or is the SUMPRODUCT function necessary to coerce Boolean logic?

Comment: The sumifs with the array criterion would return an array.  The sumproduct sums the resulting array.  The Op wanted a single number in the end not an array. @GeoffreyTurner

Comment: Hmmm. Doesn't entirely make sense to me as the SUMIF function produces a single sum by virtue of the product of arrays and then sum of the product. Wrapping inside SUMPRODUCT function would sum a [1,1] array. I'll think about more, @Scott Craner.

Comment: @GeoffreyTurner if you have office 365 you can see what it does.  Fill column A with `A` and `B` fill the same size range in column B with random numbers.  Then in C1 put `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"A","B"})` you will see it spill an array.

Comment: @ScottCraner, gotchya. I get it now - this is useful to understand. Thanks for the visual!